# Call function from component in react Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing props of form component as `addcertificate` in App.js.
And adding theses values in the state of app.js using add function 
I want to convert these :

`<Forms addcertificate={this.add} />` to route like this `<Route path=":action/id" component={IdentityPage} />`

I tried this but getting error:

```
<Route path=":action/id" component={<Forms addcertificate={this.add} />} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop to render some custom JSX.

```
<Route
  path=":action/id"
  render={() => <Forms addcertificate={this.add} />}
/>
```